# How to set button by a contour polygon? Android

Tags: android, shapes, android-button

There are two adjacent graphic buttons. If I use the method of calculation of the coordinates touch `TouchEvent`, I have to create a large array of coordinates. Maybe there is another method?

[image: ImageButton]

Comment: That is exactly how the buttons look?

Comment: No, the design is not finished, now stand at a crossroads, I want to make a trapezoidal buttons, if I find a solution to my problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably not the best solution but you could overlap two buttons each representing a part of the image(the black or white) and make the rest of the `Button`'s image transparent(the images will have the same dimensions for both buttons). You'll also need to extend the `Button` class to override how the `onTouchEvent` method handles the touch events, depending on the point where the touch happened being a transparent point or an "image" point. I've made a small sample project obtaining a `Button` with two parts like below(ignore my design skills):

[image]

You can find the [project here](https://github.com/luksprog/sasp/tree/master/widgets/OddShapedButtons), it's pretty self explanatory. See if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It helped me. However, I've found a problem with your sample.
If the drawable is not in "wrap_content" (for example, fill_parent), your project will crash. I have fixed it by creating the bitmap like that : 

Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
  ((BitmapDrawable) bkg.getCurrent()).getBitmap(),
  getWidth(), 
  getHeight(),
  true
    );

Comment: @Sebastien You are right, my code didn't take in consideration the view's size changing(or being bigger that the Bitmap itself). I've corrected the sample and I'm scaling the `Bitmap` in the `onSizeChanged` callback so it always has the correct size.

Comment: Your solution is better that mine (to do it in onSizeChanged). Thanks again :)
However, I have improved it again, before creating the bitmap, I have add this code :
// Bitmap take a lot of place in memory, free memory as soon as possible
 if (mBitmap != null){
       mBitmap.recycle();
 }