# Check whether touched Point lies inside given area or not

Tags: java, android, image, touch, hittest

Have a look at below image.

[image]

Total image is around 300X300. Inside that 1 Diamond shape is there. I know its Points as below

```
    pointA = new Point(0, 183);
    pointB = new Point(183, 0);
    pointC = new Point(366, 183);
    pointD = new Point(183, 366);
```

If I touch on this whole image, how can I detect whether touched point is inside Diamond area or outside?
I also had a look at [this](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/03/09/algorithm-to-determine-if-a-point-is-inside-a-square-with-mathematics-no-hit-test-involved/) link but could not understand some points.

Comment: did u solved the problem?

Comment: Not yet... looking for complete soln

Comment: Finally got answer. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362027/how-to-set-button-by-a-contour-polygon-android/14398104#14398104

Comment: Thanks to everyone who tried to help

Comment: Please don't add (Solved) to your titles. Mark an answer accepted instead if appropriate, or flag your question as a duplicate if you found another question that solved your problem.

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks. Will do the same from now onwards.

Answer (score 2):

create a `Shape` object from your `Points` and
check that point exists inside that `Shpae`
m not sure about this but it should be similar to this one...

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();//use your points co-ordinates 
    if (rect.contains(x,y))
     {
       //isinside
     }
```

Comment: there is also `rect.contains(your_point)` method that can be use....

Comment: I tried this. I think its taking Rectangle from (0,0). But, in above image inside object is Diamond shape. So, its returning back wrong result

Answer (score 2):

What you are referring to is the [L1 Norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29), or [Manhattan Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance). To test if your clicked point is inside your diamond (or less than an L1 norm of 183, all you need to do is do the following (in pseudo-code):

```
isInside(ClickedPoint)
{
    X=abs(ClickedPoint.x-183);
    Y=abs(Clickedpoint.y-183);

    if (X+Y<=183) return inside
    else return outside
}
```

Sorry for not including true Java code, but that shouldn't be too hard to code up.

Comment: It's up to you to code it...but the algorithm/math behind it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is rotate the touched point and the diamond points by 45 degrees:

```
public Point rotatePoint(Point pt, Point center)
{
    double cosAngle = Math.cos(45);
    double sinAngle = Math.sin(45);
    double dx = (pt.x-center.x);
    double dy = (pt.y-center.y);
    pt.x = center.x + (int) (dx*cosAngle-dy*sinAngle);
    pt.y = center.y + (int) (dx*sinAngle+dy*cosAngle);
    return pt;
}
```

create a Rect from the points:

```
Point centerPoint = new Point(183,183);
Rect r = new Rect(rotatePoint(pointA, centerPoint).x, rotatePoint(pointA, centerPoint).y, rotatePoint(pointC, centerPoint).x, rotatePoint(pointC, centerPoint).y);
```

then use test if it contains the point:

```
r.contains(rotatePoint(ClickedPoint, centerPoint))
```

This will return true if the point is in the diamond.

Comment: There is no constructor for Rect with Point as parameter...

Comment: try `Rect r = new Rect(rotatePoint(pointA, centerPoint).x, rotatePoint(pointA, centerPoint).y, rotatePoint(pointC, centerPoint).x, rotatePoint(pointC, centerPoint).y);`

Comment: anyway its the concept, rotate the diamond into a square then test if the rotated point is in the square.

Comment: its not working :( anyway, thank u for d response

Comment: The angle given to `sin` and `cos` in this example is in degrees while `Math` expects them in radians.